# AVCaptureMetadataOutput with Driver's License

Tags: ios7, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice, pdf417

I am trying to capture the data from the pdf417 2d barcodes on the back of driver's licenses using the AVCaptureMetadataOutput for iOS7.  I have the program recognizing other pdf417 barcodes, but it won't recognize the one on the back of my FL DL.  Is this something that can't be done using the AVCaptureMetadataOutput?  Has anyone had success with getting it to work?

Comment: Upon more testing I found that it can be read using the framework.  I increased the AVCaptureSession resolution settings and increased the AVCaptureDevice videoZoomFactor and it was able to pick up the DL PDF417 code on occasionally.  If someone knows how to increase the accuracy and ability to read more, the information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon more testing I found that it can be read using the framework.  I increased the AVCaptureSession resolution settings and increased the AVCaptureDevice videoZoomFactor and it was able to pick up the DL PDF417 code consistently when properly lit.  Still a difficult in some situations but I will play with built in settings to try and improve further.